# 2D boolean array creation and assigment.Compile time error

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, boolean, multidimensional-array

```
public class Test {
    boolean[][] expectedResults = new boolean[8][2];
    expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
}
```

Gives me the following Compile Time error:

test.java:3: ']' expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                        ^
test.java:3: ';' expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                         ^
test.java:3: illegal start of type
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                           ^
test.java:3:  expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                            ^
test.java:3: ';' expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                ^
test.java:3: illegal start of type
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                        ^
test.java:3:  expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                         ^
test.java:3: ';' expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                          ^
test.java:3: illegal start of type
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                            ^
test.java:3:  expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                                 ^
test.java:3: ';' expected
        expectedResults[0] = new boolean[] {false, false}; //00B
                                                  ^
test.java:4: class, interface, or enum expected
}

### Solved

Must be in a method!.

Comment: You haven't posted your actual code, because it doesn't match the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
expectedResults[0] = new boolean[]{false, false};
```

Also, make sure you perform the assignment inside a method or static initialization block.

Comment: See the second part of my answer. it should be in a method, not just in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can creating an array like this `{false, false}`, only when you put it in the same line with the decleration (`Array constants can only be used in initializers`):

```
boolean[] expectedResults = {false, false}; // complies
```

While this does not compile:

```
boolean[] expectedResults;
expectedResults = {false, false}; // does not complie
```

instead use:

```
boolean[] expectedResults;
expectedResults = new boolean[]{false, false};
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is 8x2 boolean array initialization made easy.

```
  public boolean[][] expectedResults = {
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
    {false, false},
  };
```

> This is a 4x8 boolean array initalization made easy.

```
  public boolean[][] expectedResults = {
    {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true},
    {true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true},
    {true, false, false, false, false, true, true, true},
    {false, true, true, true, true, true, true, false}
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to initialize the array like this.

```
boolean[][] expectedResults;
 expectedResults = new boolean[8][2];
```